# How come I don't built a great deal of strength quickly, yet I see countless other lifters who do?

Tags: workout-routines, strength, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery

I have outlined potential reasons as to why some get stronger faster and easier:

1.Testosterone - while it's not 100% correlated with strength, more promotes more muscle mass, which increases potential for strength. **Perhaps I have low testosterone?**

2.Genetics - while they are not a 100% make or break, some people have very poor genetics when it comes to proper CNS use, muscle size, efficiency, etc. **I have poor balance as well, and lose breath running barely 50 feet, being at a healthy weight. Maybe I have bad genes for powerlifting/fitness, and should just be a lazy, weak nerd?**

3.Biomechanics - while they again do not fully dictate things, and genetics also can cover this, some people have larger limbs, digits, hands, thickness, skeletal frame, leverage, muscle placement, recovery speeds faster, etc. **Maybe I have poor recovery speed, and bad biomechanics as well?**

4.Stress - I have constant anxiety and sleep poorly, and suffer from stress a lot due to social anxiety. **Maybe that explains why I so poorly can improve?**

So my question is, and being truthfully, aside from taking a buttload of roids, and working out, are some people just destined to fail easily at weight training?

Paradox notes:
I notice that after one week off or so I get dramatically weaker, but if I workout more than once a week I fatigue and overwork, and suffer from pain. I have worked out for years, but fatigue after several reps, and suffer pain for days if I do too many reps. My focus is only strength, so I do tend to stay with low reps, but I never get stronger. I even tried 5x5, but nothing.

Perhaps I've learned something in these years? Should I just throw in the towel and agree that aside from roids, I am a low-T, poor genetic mold of a person who works out years properly, with proper diet, and still can't compare to the average man, and admit that weight lifting is not for me?

Or is there an alternative? **And do not say working hard because I have done that all my life, used proper technique, proper diet, and have not made any gains in years.**

Comment: How are we to know what is not working in what you do if we don't know what it is that you do? Tell us the specifics of your workout schedule and diet, including sets reps weights exercises and how often and what you eat and how much...and we might be able to debug what the issue is. Without that info, this is way too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of considering what you are doing right you should be focusing on what the people you are describing are doing right.

1. Do these people actually exist?
2. If so, what are they doing?

It sounds like you've done what a lot of beginners do: Jump around with different things until you find something that makes you magically strong.

You should instead be focusing on 3 things: Diet, your program, sleep. In that order.

You can't get stronger if you don't eat enough, you can't get stronger if you don't stick to a program, and you can't get stronger if you don't give yourself time to recover.

Granted I don't know who the people you are comparing yourself to are, but I can tell you that I've countless people (myself included) throughout the years get stronger just by setting those three things.

Do you have a real diet? By real I mean having calculated caloric intake and measuring it.

Do you have a program that works via progressive overload? Have you stuck to a program for more than just a few months?

I'd focus on settling into a real diet and program rather than thinking about whether you have low testosterone or need steroids.